# API not displaying the weather information for a week - Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, macos, api, dart

The application I am trying to create should show up to 8 days of weather information, the problem I am having is that it is only showing one day. I have tried to define each day as its own variable but that isn't working, the API holds all the information but I'm really struggling on how to display this data. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ),
);

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
Future<dynamic> getUserData() async {
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
   'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?   latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&hourly=temperature_2m'));
var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  return jsonData;
 }

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Weather Page'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
   ),
   body: Center(
    child: Card(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getUserData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        var hourly = snapshot.data['hourly'];

        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            "time: ${hourly['time'][0]} - temperature_2m: ${hourly['temperature_2m'][0]}",
          ),
          subtitle: Text(
            "latitude: ${snapshot.data['latitude']}",
          ),
          trailing: Text(
            "longitude: ${snapshot.data['longitude']}",
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
),
  ),
);
  }
 }

 getUserData() {}

class User {
  final String? hourly,
  time,
  temperature_2m,
  longitude,
  generationtime_m,
   hourly_units,
  latitude;

  User(this.longitude, this.latitude, this.hourly, this.time,
  this.temperature_2m, this.generationtime_m, this.hourly_units);
}
```